# How can I filter rows where there are more than 3 observations?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, forcats

I have a simple dataset, and I'm trying to find cities with more than 3 observations `(n)`. However, I'm encountering an error when using the `fct_lump()` function. Could you help me identify the issue?

```
tablo1 |> 
  count(sehir, sort = TRUE)
```

```
sehir              n
   <chr>          <int>
 1 Adana              2
 2 Adıyaman           1
 3 Afyonkarahisar     2
 4 Aksaray            1
 5 Amasya             1
 6 Ankara            23
 7 Antalya            5
 8 Ardahan            1
 9 Artvin             1
10 Aydın              1
# ℹ 71 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Here's the current code that results in an error:

```
tablo1 |> 
  count(sehir) |>
  filter(fct_lump(sehir, 5, w = n))
```

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `fct_lump(sehir, 5, w = n)`.
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be a logical vector, not a <factor> object.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `fct_lump(sehir, 5, w = n)`.
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be a logical vector, not a <factor> object.
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. ├─dplyr::filter(count(tablo1, sehir), fct_lump(sehir, 5, w = n))
 2. ├─dplyr:::filter.data.frame(count(tablo1, sehir), fct_lump(sehir, 5, w = n))
 3. │ └─dplyr:::filter_rows(.data, dots, by)
 4. │   └─dplyr:::filter_eval(...)
 5. │     ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 6. │     └─mask$eval_all_filter(dots, env_filter)
 7. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
 8. └─dplyr:::dplyr_internal_error(...)
Run rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE) to see 5 hidden frames.
```

Comment: Why not use `filter(n>3)`??

Comment: I want to group the remaining rows as "Other" to see them collectively in a variable named "Other".

Comment: so you are not trying to filter your data but rather collapse it such that those with less than 3 observations are collapsed  as others. use `summarize` and not `filter`

Comment: If you do want to filter (rather than summarize), the problem is that `filter()` requires a logical expression to be evaluated.  In your code `filter(fct_lump(sehir, 5, w = n))  `, there is no logical expression, only producing a variable with `fct_lump()`.  If you said something like `filter(fct_lump(sehir, 5, w = n) == "Other")`,   that would let you see only the observations coded as "Other".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `fct_lump` & co you might want to start with uncounted values; with `fct_lump_min(..., min = 4)` you'd be left with factor levels with *"more than 3 observations"* + *Other* which you can then count:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(forcats)

# uncount first to get "original" dataset
tablo1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="
sehir              n
1 Adana              2
2 Adıyaman           1
3 Afyonkarahisar     2
4 Aksaray            1
5 Amasya             1
6 Ankara            23
7 Antalya            5
8 Ardahan            1
9 Artvin             1
10 Aydın              1") |>
  tidyr::uncount(n) |>
  as_tibble()
glimpse(tablo1)
#> Rows: 38
#> Columns: 1
#> $ sehir <chr> "Adana", "Adana", "Adıyaman", "Afyonkarahisar", "Afyonkarahisar"…

tablo1 |>
  mutate(sehir = fct_lump_min(sehir, 4)) |>
  count(sehir)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   sehir       n
#>   <fct>   <int>
#> 1 Ankara     23
#> 2 Antalya     5
#> 3 Other      10
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>